# Error initializing Evernote API

Tags: evernote

Hi
I am developing an application on android(3.0) and trying to use the Evernot API. I downloaded Evernote API with sample and trying to play with it. 
I working with evernote sample application name "HelloEDAM" , when i run the application following error displays at screen 
"Error initializing Evernote API".. i have the API consumer secret and consumer Key which is send by Evernote to me and also providing the right username and password. Any idea what could be the problem?

many thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

That error is shown if we're unable to authenticate to Evernote. Common causes of this are:

- Your application doesn't have internet permissions
- Your consumer key and consumer secret are incorrect
- You requested a web service API key, which must authenticate using OAuth, but are attempting to authenticate using username & password
- You are using an Evernote username and password from our production service but are attempting to authenticate against our sandbox server

We also log a message that contains the exception that caused the error.

Comment: Thank you Seth, i will try your suggestion and then get back to you. Thanks alot

Comment: "You are using an Evernote username and password from our production service but are attempting to authenticate against our sandbox server"